# Why can't I call fetch on jest with vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs, babeljs, fetch

I'm kind of new to testing library, and recently started studying Jest. I'm currently trying to implement vanilla javascript project with jest.

I know 'mocking' an async API call in jest is best practice, but I wanted to actually call API using fetch to see if jest works correctly. But I got stuck on 'fetch' request. Need to remind you that my project is not node project, just plain vanilla javascript project.

Before moving on to actual test code, since I'm using babel and webpack on my project. Here's **.bablerc.js** and **webpack.config.js** implementation.

> .babelrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/env',
      {
        targets: {
          browsers: ['> 0.25%, not dead'],
        },
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: 3,
        shippedProposals: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

> webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'static/js/main.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    inline: true,
    hot: true,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: true,
      ignored: '/node_modules/',
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Typing Game',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
      },
      hash: true,
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'static/css/styles.css' }),
  ],
};
```

With project configuration above, webpack and webpack-dev-server worked perfectlly and could retrieve completely built html, css and js files. After checking everything except Jest works perfectly, I implemented simple API call function that gets list of words in array,

```
export const getWordsAPI = () =>
  fetch(
    'https://server-api-address'
  ).then((res) => res.json());
```

And tried to call the api function on my jest test code.

```
import { getWordsAPI } from '../src/js/api';

describe('Integration with getWords API', () => {
  test('Get Word List', async () => {
    const result = await getWordsAPI();
    expect(result).toEqual([
      {
        text: 'hello',
      },
      {
        text: 'world',
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

But, I continuously got this 'fetch is not defined' error.

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

> 1 | export const getWordsAPI = () =>
    |                            ^
  2 |   fetch(
  3 |     'https://server-api-address'
  4 |   ).then((res) => res.json());

  at getWordsAPI (src/js/api.js:1:28)
  at _callee$ (__tests__/api.test.js:5:26)
  at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)        
  at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:22)
  at Generator.next (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:118:21) 
  at asyncGeneratorStep (__tests__/api.test.js:11:103)
  at _next (__tests__/api.test.js:13:194)
  at __tests__/api.test.js:13:364
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/api.test.js:13:97)
```

I tried everything to solve this problem, including **jest-fetch-mock** but couldn't solve the problem. when I applied **jest-fetch-mock** to test code, I got new error which is this.

```
invalid json response body at reason unexpected end of json input
```

I eventually ended up using **isomorphic-fetch** library to make fetch work on my test code, which makes me uncomfortable.

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { getWordsAPI } from '../src/js/api';

describe('Integration with getWords API', () => {
    ...
}
```

I understand **fetch is not defined** error happening on **nodejs** environment, since there is not **fetch** provided by node, but this is vanilla javascript project. **fetch** is provided by default on browser, and should work without any additional work. But why is this error happening? I don't know what is causing this problem, either babel or webpack or even jest itself.

Please teach me what I'm missing. Probably I'm missing the main concept of Jest architecture, related to this problem. Waiting for anyone's response

---

ps. In case you need to know what version of libraries I'm using in my project, here's my package.json file. Other than libraries, I'm using WSL2 on Windows OS, and using npm instead of yarn.

```
{
  "name": "typing_game",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Typing Game by Vanilla Javascript",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "piecemakerz <piecemakerz@naver.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.1",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.7.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.29.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *But why is this error happening?* - it's unclear what the concern is. It's correct that fetch is available in browsers but not in Node. Browser != Node. That it's vanilla JS, or React, or whatever else doesn't matter. It could be available in a browser but the test runs in Node, and there's no `fetch` global variable in Node, unless you explicitly polyfill it whit isomorphic-fetch or else.

Comment: *I'm kind of new to testing library* - then the first thing to learn is that real network requests aren't usually performed in tests, except for e2e (Jest isn't efficient for e2e) or some variations of integration tests. You don't need to polyfill fetch but to mock it. *I tried everything to solve this problem, including jest-fetch-mock but couldn't solve the problem.* - then you can start with solving this problem because mocking it is a correct approach, and giving up on things without understanding why they failed isn't very effective.

Comment: *I wanted to actually call API using fetch to see if jest works correctly* - it works correctly, as long as fetch polyfill works correctly. It may work in Node but not in a browser, or vice versa, because a polyfill isn't fully spec compliant. Since you're efficiently testing third-party polyfill that may differ from how real app works in a browser, there's not much value in such test, it just slows down test run, makes it flaky and tests *something*. This is the reason why real requests are usually performed in browser e2e. Consider updating the question with your attempt on fetch mocking.

Comment: @EstusFlask First of all, thanks for your detailed comment. Help me a lot to fix my knowledge about testing. I thought Jest test runs on its 'Fake Web Browser' environment, which provides fetch. But based on your comment, Jest runs its test on 'Node Server' environment, which doesn't provide fetch. That's why 'fetch is not defined' error occurred continuously. So I changed fetch to axios... and everything worked correctly!

Just to be sure, I'm calling actual api on Jest just to check how Jest testing flow works, have no others meaning. I'll change my jest code using moke from now. Thanks.

Comment: @EstusFlask If anything from what I wrote above is wrong, feel free to comment. I'm always eager to learn what's right.